Conditionally load or add another middleware in the chain during current middleware
When using Gin framework for Go, I'm writing some custom middleware. One of my new middleware will evaluate if the request coming in is from my front-end SPA. If it is, I want to also use the sessions middleware to create/load the user session info. If it is not, then I don't want to call that middleware.
I can't seem to find how (if possible) to do this. I was hoping I could either use an IF block when I'm defining my router.Use(xyz) statements, or better yet, tell my current middleware to load another one before I call the c.Next().
Example:
func MyMiddleware(c *gin.Context) {
    isFromFrontend := myFunctionToDetermine()
    c.Set("isFromFrontend", isFromFrontend)
    if isFromFrontend {
        <here is where i'd like to effectively call r.Use() again and pass the session middleware>
    }
    c.Next()
}

r := gin.Default()
r.Use(MyMiddleware)


I tried the other method of defining middleware where I:

created a new function for MyMiddleware that accepts an instance of the router, so that I can try to call the .Use() method again from within my middleware; it doesn't error but it also doesn't seem to call it. I'm guessing that the middleware chain is already established before it is evaluated?

Is there a way to add a new middleware to the existing chain before it finishes processing?
Or is there maybe some other entirely different way to accomplish what I'm doing?

Related: an example of a reconfigurable CORS middleware (not compatible with Gin, though).

Do you mean you want to execute some code at that point if a condition is fulfilled ? do not change the sequence of middlewares, just call the function

At the end of the day,  gin middleware is defined as a gin.HandlerFunc, namely func(gin.Context).
So conditionally calling a middleware is easy enough
func setupMyMiddleware(conditional gin.HandlerFunc){
  return func(c gin.Context) {
     if c.GetBool("isFromFrontend") {
        conditional(c)
     }
     // Do something else, if necessary
     
     // Call the next handler
     c.Next()
  }
}
//...
r := gin.Default()
r.Use(setupMyMiddleware(myOtherMiddleware))

It is basically like writing a conditional http Middleware, only the signature of the middleware is slightly different.

Thank you! This was exactly what I needed. I was so close as I was playing around, but didn't get there on my own. New to Go, and trying to mimic some of the Laravel framework stuff since I'm a big fan of how it handles, well, everything. I can't upvote your answer because I'm on a new account with no reputation - long time reader, first time poster.

@Poseidon No problem. The rep is… secondary, at least to me. “The good thing about knowledge? You can share it without losing anything.” Ray Mears
